# How to give a href to redirect to a page in worpdress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, href

I want the user to click arrow and it will redirect to myproject page in wordpress. Please let me know how to give a link to a page in wp.

```html
<i class="bi-arrow-right"></i>
```

The code is mentioned below.

```html
<a class="circle-link" href="<?php echo $project07['project_link']; ?>">
    <span class="circle-icon">
       <i class="bi-arrow-right"></i>
    </span>
    <span>View Project</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you facing some issue or error with your code? If yes then show the error also

Comment: What's $project07 ?

Comment: You can handle this via JS also

Comment: No error. currently it's redirecting to no where.  it's giving an error array to string conversion,

Comment: Are you sure $project07['project_link'] is a string ?

Comment: Did you create a page or post for that link?  And if yes, check your hyperlinks to find out about your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var yourUrl = "https://yoururl.com";
$(".circle-link").attr('href',yourUrl);
})
</script>
```

Add this in at the end of the page WordPress page. I hope this helps and this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because probably `$project07['project_link']` is an array.
`var_dump()` this value and see what is the structure of that array.
If you are using the ACF for wordpress, you should be able to access the link after writing `<?= $project07['project_link']['url']; ?>`